# I can't figure out how to close a simple popup

Tags: javascript, popup

Sorry, for the simplistic question.
I am not sure if all of this is important or not, but I will mention it just in case. : When a user clicks a link, this is what happens:

```
function begin(some info) is called->Makes an Ajax request to backend PHP->
PHP calls the callback function->Callback function calls another JS function that creates a popup->
In the popup creating function, The Save button is assigned a function that makes an ajax request and sends PHP some user input.->
PHP makes a callback to another function that does nothing.
```

Here, this is the function that puts together the popup box.

```
function collection(name, description, data){
    var json = data;
    var cont = openSitePopup("400","300");
    //We create div objects.
    var namecell = ce("div","sitePopupCell");   
    //Stuff
    // We create a button and assign the createProducts Method to it.
    var sbtbutton = createBtn("submitObject","SAVE","createProducts()");
    //We append all the div objects to the popup.   
    cont.appendChild(namecell);
    //..
}

function openSitePopup(width,height) {

//try to center the popup if values are not passed
var xPos = (getWinWidth()/2) - (width/2) + sl;
var yPos = (getWinHeight()/2) - (height/2) + st;

sitepopupwin = ge("sitePopupWin");
clearElement(sitepopupwin);

var winhandle = ce("div","","sitePopupHandle");

sitepopupwin.style.display = "block";
//Other style assignments.  

//closebutton
var close = ce("img","sitePopupCloseBtn");
close.setAttribute("src",theme_path + "/images/icons/close.png");

//start adding goodies
var mydiv = ce("div","sitePopupContainer");

winhandle.appendChild(close);
winhandle.appendChild(createCleaner());
sitepopupwin.appendChild(winhandle);
sitepopupwin.appendChild(mydiv);

//return reference to the container for adding stuff
return mydiv;
}

function createProducts()
{
    //Some exciting Ajax stuff with a callback to writeNewFolder()
}

function writeNewFolder(data){
    //Nothing of interest here...yet.
}
```

Now, when I press the `Save` button on the popup, the request is made successfully, but the popup does not close. I know of the `Window.Close()` function, but it didn't work. `cont.Close()` seems like an obvious choice, but in that case, I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'Close'` So, Cont is only a div element. The `openSitePopup()` method only returns a div.

Thanks for all your help.

edit:

```
function ce(elementType,elementClass,elementId,txt) {

var e = document.createElement(elementType);

//add optional parameters
if (elementId) e.setAttribute("id",elementId);
if (elementClass) setClass(e,elementClass);

//append extra text.  If passed an object, append with without the textnode wrapper
if (isData(txt)) {
    if (typeof(txt)=="object") e.appendChild(txt);
    else e.appendChild(ctnode(txt));
}

return e;

}
```

Hopefully the original creator does not mind me posting some of his code here. Well, it's free and open source, so it should be fine...I think.

edit 2: The `ge` function. This one is simple.

```
function ge(element) {
return document.getElementById(element);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not post the functions ge and ce that creates the popup which is NOT a `window` hence you cannot `.close()` it

try

`ge('sitePopupWin').style.display='none';`

or

```
var popup = ge('sitePopupWin');
popup.parentNode.removeChild(popup);
```

Comment: My apologies! I thought `ce` was a standard JavaScript function. It basically creates an element. I will add it in.

Comment: Your solution worked, thanks a lot. You were right, it's not a window element, just a div. How interesting.